# Write code for Intel Edisons' Quark CPU

Tags: real-time, yocto, rtos, intel-edison

Is there any way to write code for the Quark CPU on the Intel Edison and establish a communication between the Quark CPU, which is - as far as i know - running an RTOS, and the Atom CPU, which is running Yocto.

I've googled for some tutorials but didn't find any.

Thank you guys!

Answer (score 0):

According to several postings in the Intel forum it is not supported at this [time](https://communities.intel.com/thread/59878)